# How to prevent the below TextFields to be hidden behind the keyboard when one is focused (this causes an undesirable manual scroll)

Tags: flutter, keyboard, textfield

When the keyboard is previously dismissed and i click on a TextField, the keyboard is toggled and this TextField is focused. However the keyboard is blocking the below TextFields, and it requires either a manual scroll from the user, or a `textInputAction: TextInputAction.next` to reach the next TextField.

Is there a way to show the most TextFields possible, without requiring a controller to control the scrolling behavior.

Note: In my widget tree i have

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      child: Column(
        children: [ ...
```

Here is a view of the issue : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiZ9w.gif

Thanks for your help